# Too many cartesian products, making query to run slower

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, cartesian-product

Consider I have two tables DETAILS AND RATE with following columns:

DETAILS table:

```
CREATE TABLE DETAILS(
LONG ID PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
DOUBLE PRICE1,
DOUBLE PRICE2,
DOUBLE PRICE3,
VARCHAR(25) CURRENCY,
DATE CREATED_DATE,
VARCHAT(50) COMPLETED
..................
Few more columns
);
```

RATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE RATE(
LONG ID PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
DOUBLE RATE,
VARCHAR(25) CURRENCY,
DATE CREATED_DATE
..................
Few more columns
);
```

And I have a update query for DETAILS table as shown bellow.

```
UPDATE DETAILS D, RATE R 
SET D.PRICE1=D.PRICE1*R.RATE,
D.PRICE2=D.PRICE2*R.RATE,
D.PRICE3=D.PRICE3*R.RATE
WHERE
D.CURRENCY=R.CURRENCY AND 
DATE(D.CREATED_DATE) = DATE(R.CREATED_DATE) AND
D.COMPLETED IS NULL OR DO.COMPLETED='ABC' AND
D.CURRENCY!='RUPEE';
```

Before the query was working fine but as table grown this query is started taking more time and it is giving cartesion product in terms of **billions**.

Is there any way I can optimise this query?
Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Can you post the output of the `EXPLAIN UPDATE....` query please?

Comment: Can you list the indexes you have on each table?

Comment: Hi Simon, For each run we are inserting both the tables with new data and once data is inserted then we are calling this update query to update the data.

Comment: Mark, We don't have indexing for these tables except primary key

Answer (score 1):

Use explicit `join`s and fix the `where` clause using parentheses:

```
UPDATE DETAILS D JOIN
       RATE R 
       ON D.CURRENCY=R.CURRENCY AND 
          DATE(D.CREATED_DATE) = DATE(R.CREATED_DATE)
  SET D.PRICE1 = D.PRICE1*R.RATE,
      D.PRICE2 = D.PRICE2*R.RATE,
      D.PRICE3 = D.PRICE3*R.RATE
WHERE (D.COMPLETED IS NULL OR DO.COMPLETED='ABC') AND
      D.CURRENCY <> 'RUPEE';
```

The problem is the parentheses in the `where` clause.  However, you simply should not use commas to mean `join`.

Answer (score 0):

`DATE(D.CREATED_DATE) = DATE(R.CREATED_DATE)`

Since those fields are DATE datatype, there is no need to use the DATE() function.  In fact, doing so prevents use of an index.

Add `INDEX(currency, created_date)` at least to `RATE`.  This, plus the above change will greatly speed up the query.

Another improvement would be to make `currency` an ENUM or normalize it.